# What Statistical Tool To Measure The Weirdness

Tags: bias, stationarity

Scenario:

> Roughly 50 million voters vote for a certain Yes/No poll. Results
>   start to come in and when the 10% of the votes are counted the difference
>   between “no” and “yes” is roughly 3 million on behalf of “no”. The net
>   difference (3 million) go almost unchanged until 80% of the votes are
>   counted. At the end, the net difference is roughly 1.2 million on
>   behalf of “no”.

I find this unnatural. Is there a way to measure how (if at all) unnatural it is?

(I chose “bias” as the tag, but not sure if it is appropriate.)

Comment: Two basic facts about counting votes: (1) different regions tend to vote differently (2) different regions count their votes at different speeds. In the United States,  dense, urban areas tend to take longer to count their votes and tend to vote Democratic. Statewide elections in Illinois can change depending on whether results from the city of Chicago have come in. A simple [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) would be that the mean of the first 80% of the votes is the same as the mean of the last 20% of the votes. But can the result be reasonably explained by geography?

Comment: This question is really not clear to understand.

Comment: @Michael Just as an extreme example: If you were told that (assuming somewhat uniform counting) when %50 of the votes counted it was all for “no”, and when 100% was counted “yes” and “no” was equal. Whatever it means, it is not natural. I want to know is there method that would give some insight as to how unnatural it is.

Comment: It does sound a little strange but I do not see how statistical methods can help.  I think Matthew makes an plausible argument.

Comment: I'm voting too broad. A reasonable null hypothesis would allow different regions to: (i) have different vote proportions and (ii) return results at different times. From the available information, I don't see how you can reasonably test if such a null were violated. This may be a good paper topic but not a good StackExchange question.

Comment: (+1, voting to keep open.) I think this question has a plain and interesting interpretation: let the null hypothesis be that the poll results are a sequence of iid random variables.  Construct a *sequential* test of this hypothesis.  More abstractly: in a Binomial random walk on the integers (with unknown probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ for steps up and down) that ends at $1.2\times 10^6$ after (say) $10^7$ steps, how likely is it to observe a value of $3\times 10^6$ or greater at some intermediate point?

Comment: @whuber I agree that's a reasonable interpretation of the OP's question, but if you overwhelmingly reject, what does it mean? Maybe simply the iid assumption is wrong? Let $X$ be the vote share for no in Illinois but outside Chicago. Let $Y$ be the vote share for no inside Chicago. Let's say you first observe $X$ = 53.5% and then observe $Y$ = 42.5%. Is this unnatural? Not necessarily.

Comment: I added the [tag:non-stationary] tag, which seems to be the issue? This is roughly equivalent to "different populations sampled at different times". (OP: feel free to change)

Comment: I see no reason to close this; it's very clear and it isn't very broad - although it may have no good answer, that doesn't seem like a reason to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the percentage of "no" as a function of time or of the share of voters that have voted (regardless of their vote) in their actual order. 
The difference in ( max - min ) values of this function can serve as the weirdness measure.

To have a practically usable metric one might need to impose some limitations as to minimal acceptable steps (voting group size) to smooth the data or put this value in relation to the final result (percentage).

In the situation where one is interested in how close the actual shape is to the extreme situation one can define the maximal theoretical weirdness of the dataset.  Per definition it's the maximal value of the weirdness measure over all permutations of the voting schedules.

The ratio of the actually exhibited weirdness to the maximal theoretical weirdness could show whether there is some additional effect but the difference inbetween of voting preferences of the smallest voting groups.

Vice versa the  selection of the voting groups in random order can show the minimal theoretically achievable weirdness. 
Etc.

Another thing to consider, to describe the weirdness of a 2D shape (the voting curve) one needs some ideal shape to compare to. If this shape is a straight line (null hypothesis?) then you could measure the area between two lines, for example. Again consider norming it so it itself becomes comparable between elections.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what you mean by "weirdness", but a simple approach would be to define this in terms of a [null-hypothesis](/questions/tagged/null-hypothesis) that the votes are an unbiased sample of the population (e.g. [survey-sampling](/questions/tagged/survey-sampling)).

Under the null model, the number of "yes" votes $k$ will follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)
$$k\sim\mathrm{Bin}(p,n)$$
where $n$ is the total number of votes tallied so far, and $p$ is the **final** fraction of "yes" votes (after *all* votes are counted).

For simplicity you can use the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)
$$k\sim\mathrm{N}_{\mu,\sigma^2}\,,\,\mu=np\,\,,\sigma^2=np(1-p)$$

For a given $k$ and $n$, the margin of "no" over "yes" is
$$\hat{k}=n-2k$$
so the [$z$-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_score) of $k$ gives a simple measure of "weirdness"
$$z=\frac{k-\mu}{\sigma}$$
(note that $\hat{k}$ has the same $z$-score as $k$)

So putting it all together, a simple "weirdness" would be
$$z_{\mathrm{weird}}=\left|\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right|\,,\,p=\frac{K}{N}$$
where $K$ and $N$ are the population parameters (i.e. all votes tallied).

So for your example we have $p=\frac{24.4}{50}=48.8\%$, and the comparisons are (#'s in millions) ...

- Early: $n=0.1N=5$, $\hat{k}=3$ so $k=1$, $\mu=2.44$, $\sigma\approx{1.12}\times{10}^{-3}$ giving $|z|\approx{1288}$
- Late: $n=0.8N=40$, $\hat{k}=3$ so $k=18.5$, $\mu=19.52$, $\sigma\approx{3.16}\times{10}^{-3}$ giving $|z|\approx{323}$

So by this measure, the early results are much "weirder" than the later results, but both are very weird.

So neglecting the sequential aspect, the incremental vote-tally snapshots are **not** consistent with random samples from the final population.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to understand your explanation/reasoning. Which part corresponds to the fact that the net 3 million difference continued unchanged between 10% and and 80%?

Comment: Your computations of the $Z$ scores at the end are grossly wrong because you have forgotten that your units are *millions*.  Your value of $1.29$ should actually be $1288$.  Your approach overall neglects to account for the fact that the statistics have to be viewed as a *sequence* of z-scores rather than just a single z-score: that appreciably changes the threshold of significance.  (Nevertheless, a value of $1288$ will be found to be significant!)

Comment: @whuber oops! I edited to include the sqrt(1e6) factor. Wouldn't the sequential aspect just make the conclusion more extreme? (i.e. repeatedly getting a difference of 3e6 over many steps would be much more unlikely than just getting it at any single step)

Comment: It makes it less extreme: it's much more likely that you will see a large Z-score on such a random walk than if you were testing a single random sample.

Comment: @whuber OK. I thought the OP was referring to a *run* of near 3e6 vote difference, over the time from 10% to 80% of votes tallied. Your comment to the OP, and above, seems to be about a single snapshot instead? (I may be confused, though!)

Comment: I see exactly two statistics given in the question: one concerns the returns after five million ballots are counted and the other concerns the returns after all fifty million are counted.  I can't find a way to interpret either of those as a "run." What is ambiguous concerns how the first statistic was selected: is that the only intermediate statistic that was collected or is it in some way perhaps *the most extreme deviation* encountered in the sequence of all fifty million results?

Comment: It was this that gave me the impression of a run: "... when the 10% of the votes are counted the difference between “no” and “yes” is roughly 3 million on behalf of “no”. The net difference (3 million) *go almost unchanged until* 80% of the votes are counted." I had interpreted that there was a sequence of statistics between the two, all of which had a similar net difference. This was probably an over-interpretation :)